# Long winded Excel formula needs simplifying

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way I can simplify this formula?

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEN(RIGHT(K3,LEN(K3)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(K3," ","@",LEN(K3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(K3," ",""))))))<4,IF(LEN(RIGHT(K3,LEN(K3)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(K3," ","@",LEN(K3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(K3," ",""))))))< 3,IF(LEN("00"&LEFT(RIGHT(K3,2),1)+1&"l")>4,"0"&LEFT(RIGHT(K3,2),1)+1&"l","00"&LEFT(RIGHT(K3,2),1)+1&"l"),IF(LEN("0"&LEFT(RIGHT(K3,3),2)+1&"l")<4,"00"&LEFT(RIGHT(K3,3),2)+1&"l","0"&LEFT(RIGHT(K3,3),2)+1&"l")),IF(LEN(LEFT(RIGHT(K3,4),3)+1&"l")<4,IF(LEN(LEFT(RIGHT(K3,4),3)+1&"l")< 3,"00"&LEFT(RIGHT(K3,4),3)+1&"l","0"&LEFT(RIGHT(K3,4),3)+1&"l"),(LEFT(RIGHT(K3,4),3)+1&"l"))),IF(LEN(K3)<4,IF(LEN(K3)< 3,IF(LEN("00"&LEFT(K3,1)+1&"l")>4,"0"&LEFT(K3,1)+1&"l","00"&LEFT(K3,1)+1&"l"),IF(LEN("0"&LEFT(K3,2)+1&"l")<4,"00"&LEFT(K3,2)+1&"l","0"&LEFT(K3,2)+1&"l")),IF(LEN(LEFT(K3,3)+1&"l")< 3,"00" & LEFT(K3,3)+1&"l", IF(LEN(LEFT(K3,3)+1&"l")<4,"0"&LEFT(K3,3)+1&"l",LEFT(K3,3)+1&"l"))))
```

It had to find the last number in the cell, add 1 to it and put an a L at the end. If the number was under 3 digits then 0's would have to be added before the number (083, 071, 043, 005, 002 etc).

```
Input          - Output

1L             - 002L
03R            - 004L
483L           - 484L
232R 233L 234L - 235L
08L 009L       - 010L
4L 005R 6R     - 007L
89L 90R 91L    - 092L
```

Comment: Have you considered using the TEXT and REPT functions?

Comment: I am not familiar with them functions. I will research them now.

Comment: From the looks of things there is potential to reduce my formula length by 75+%.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for your examples:

```
=TEXT(-LOOKUP(2,-MID(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(K3," ",REPT(" ",1000)),1000)),1,ROW($1:$15)))+1,"000L")
```

Answer (score 6):

Another one using FILTERXML:

```
=TEXT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(K3,LEN(K3)-1)," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()]")+1,"000")&"L"
```

[image]

Comment: I will have to study your formula in more depth. It uses multiple functions I do not recognize.

Comment: @VendorEagleLimited FILTERXML allows you to use XPath to process an XML document.  The formula converts the string to XML and then uses XPath to find the last number.

Answer (score 5):

I have the tested the following and I think it fulfills your criteria

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(B3," ",REPT(" ",100)),100)), RIGHT(B3, 1), "")+1, "000")&"L"
```